# pandas pivot_table apply aggfunc last instance

Tags: python, pandas

I have made a pivot table with various columns and have applied aggfunc like np.sum and first and count. I want last instance of corresponding value of a column from a dataframe. Is there any function that could serve this purpose?

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use

```
aggfunc='last'
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Age':[35, 37, 40, 29, 31, 26, 28],
                   'City':['B', 'Ch', 'LA', 'Ch', 'B', 'B', 'Ch'],
                   'Position':['M','M','M','P', 'P','M','M']})
print (df)
   Age City Position
0   35    B        M
1   37   Ch        M
2   40   LA        M
3   29   Ch        P
4   31    B        P
5   26    B        M
6   28   Ch        M

print (df.pivot_table(index='Position', columns='City', values='Age', aggfunc='last'))
City         B    Ch    LA
Position                  
M         26.0  28.0  40.0
P         31.0  29.0   NaN
```

Comment: how can you use `'first'` or `'last'`when there are several columns on which you want to aggregate (in other words, how do you specify `'first'` or `'last'` in a list  for the `aggfunc` argument)? This throws an error in my case even though it works for a single column (no list specified for the `values` and the `aggfunc` argument).

Comment: For anyone who comes here, using `last` in `aggfunc` returns the last value ignoring all the missing values that could have been last.